# text box with focusnext when enter press in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have multiple text boxes like

```
<input type="text" id="text1" onkeypress="goNext(event,this.id);"/>
<input type="text" id="text2" onkeypress="goNext(event,this.id);"/>
<input type="text" id="text3" onkeypress="goNext(event,this.id);"/>
```

Here I am trying to do a function that when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key on any text box ,the focus will go to next element.
I wrote a JavaScript function:

```
function goNext(evt, obj) {
    var curEle = obj;
    if (typeof evt == 'undefined' && window.event) {
        evt = window.event;
    }
    if (evt.keyCode == 13) {      
        $(curEle).next().focus();
    }
}
```

This is not working. How to solve this? Here I am getting `id` when I add `alert(this.id)` in the function `goNext(evt, obj)`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript function after pressing enter key on text box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25262300/javascript-function-after-pressing-enter-key-on-text-box)

Comment: Tagged `jquery`. About `Javascript`. ?

Comment: If you use jQuery, how comes you use inline JS and all this `if (typeof evt == 'undefined' && window.event)` stuff?

Comment: @abhitalks there is `$(curEle).next().focus();` :) One line with using jQuery.

Comment: @chipChocolate.py actually this question is about focusing `<input>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing the id of the element instead of the element itself to the function. So your code passes strings to the jQuery constructor, and as `text*` strings don't select any element your code fails to select the target element. Either pass the element (`this`) to the function, or concatenate `#` with the `obj` string for generating a selector.

```
goNext(event, this);
```

And if you are loading jQuery, use it. The following code will select the next matching element in the DOM and focus on it:

```
var $input = $('input[type=text]').on('keyup', function(e) {
      if (e.which == 13) {
          $input.eq( $input.index(this) + 1 ).focus();
      }
});
```

In case that you want to focus on the first input when there is no next element:

```
if (e.which == 13) {
    var $next = $input.eq( $input.index(this) + 1 );
    if ( $next.length )
         $next.focus();
    else 
         $input.first().focus();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zj89vkbj/

Comment: By the way, you can mention that the only error in original code (despite the fact that it uses inline JS and doesn't use full power of jQuery) is in passing `this.id` instead of `this` to `goNext` function.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work if you prepend a `# sign` before using your `textbox id` like,

```
if (evt.keyCode == 13) {      
    $('#'+curEle).next().focus();
//-----^ # for recognize id  in jquery
}
```

You can run the snippet to test it.

```js
function goNext(evt, obj) {
  var curEle = obj;
  if (typeof evt == 'undefined' && window.event) {
    evt = window.event;
  }
  if (evt.keyCode == 13) {      
    $('#'+curEle).next().focus();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="text1" onkeypress="goNext(event,this.id);"/>
<input type="text" id="text2" onkeypress="goNext(event,this.id);"/>
<input type="text" id="text3" onkeypress="goNext(event,this.id);"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction(current, nextFieldID) {
            document.getElementById(nextFieldID).focus();
            
        }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txtFirst" onkeypress="myFunction(this, 'txtSecond')"  />
    <input type="text" id="txtSecond" onkeyup="myFunction(this, 'txtthird')"  />
    <input type="text" id="txtthird"  />
```